# DOMJudge Installation in VMware

Tags: code-editor, online-compilation

Can DOMJudge be installed on VMWare? If so can the DOMServer, Judgehost and Teams, all be created in a single VM instance? What is the complete procedure? This is just to verify before going for AWS. I referred to the documentation but couldn't understand it fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no technical barriers to doing this. However, the teams would need workstations to work on the problems and submit them, so I do not really understand how you'd install the teams in a VMware vm.

You can add the Judgehost to the same VM but I would not recommend it. Ideally you'd run the Judgehost on the same type of hardware that the teams use to work on the problem set. If not, I'd recommend to run it in a separate VM's, and depending on the size of your contest, to run a few Judgehosts.